# Add custom column in Magento Grid which field taken from xref table

Tags: php, magento

In Magento Grid, I need to add a custom column (section_name) which field is taken from another database table through intermediary xref table. In Grid.php I tried with these codes:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('module/items')->getCollection()
    ->getSelect()->join('section_name',
    'module/sections',
    'section_name',
    'table_sections.section_id=table_sections_items_xref.section_id',
    '{{table}}.item_id=table_sections_items_xref.item_id',
    'left'
    );

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

$this->addColumn('section_name', array (
    'header' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Section Name'), 
    'type' => 'text',
    'index' => 'section_name',
));
```

Comment: 1) Which Grid.php, and 2) what is the value of `$collection->load(true)`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The Grid.php is located under app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Section category. Interestingly, when I tried var_dump($collection->load(true)); I got Unrecognized method 'load()' error.

Comment: Given that error, you have an issue with your collection class definition, definition location, and/or resource model configuration.

Comment: Thanks benmarks. I fed up :) and ended with simply removing that custom field. Don't know else what to do :)